# Data not shown after angular http request

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net web services with angular js , returning a list of customers
$http get success but data is not shown when i iterate it on the html below

```
<div ng-app="crudModule" ng-controller="CRUD_OperController" name="myForm" novalidate class="my-form">
    <ol data-ng-repeat="cus in Customers">
        <li>{{ cus.CustomerId }} ,{{ cus.CustomerName }},{{  cus.CustomerAddress }}
    </ol>
</div>
```

is there any binding problem?

my script is below

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('crudModule', []);

    app.service('studentService', function ($http) {
        this.getAllCustomers = function () {
        var response = $http.get("CustomerService.asmx/GetCustomers");
        return response;
        };
    });


    app.controller('CRUD_OperController', function ($scope, studentService) {
        $scope.Customers = [];

        loadData();

        function loadData() {
            var promiseGet = studentService.getAllCustomers();
            promiseGet.then(
                function (pl) {
                    $scope.Customers = pl.data;
                },
                function (errorPl) {
                    $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
                }
            );
        }

    }); 

</script>
```

when write  console.info(pl.data); Data comes as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfCustomers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Customers>
    <CustomerId>1</CustomerId>
    <CustomerName>Hamid</CustomerName>
    <CustomerAddress>Dhaka</CustomerAddress>
  </Customers>
  <Customers>
     <CustomerId>2</CustomerId>
     <CustomerName>Milon</CustomerName>
     <CustomerAddress>Dhaka</CustomerAddress>
  </Customers>
 <Customers>
      <CustomerId>3</CustomerId>
      <CustomerName>Jakir</CustomerName>
      <CustomerAddress>Dhaka</CustomerAddress>
 </Customers>
  <Customers>
     <CustomerId>4</CustomerId>
     <CustomerName>Hamid</CustomerName>
     <CustomerAddress>Khulna</CustomerAddress>
  </Customers>
  </ArrayOfCustomers>
```

Comment: Please share the objects of `$scope.Customers` array in the post.

Comment: Try `return response.data` instead of `response`.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JPc55j?p=preview)</kbd> for you.

I'd like recommend `angular-xml` to handle `<xml>` response of angular.

More detail at [angular-xml](https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-xml) , and dependence [x2js](https://github.com/abdmob/x2js).

1. Include `x2js` and `angular-xml` into your project.
2. Inject `xml` module to your application and config `httpProvider`.

> The HTTP interceptor will convert all your XML responses in to a JavaScript Object.

```
var app = angular.module('crudModule', ['xml']);

app.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('xmlHttpInterceptor');
});
```

3. Be careful with your response data structure.

> By console.info(pl), check the nested structure of result object parsed from xml

```
function loadData() {
    var promiseGet = studentService.getAllCustomers();
    promiseGet.then(
      function(pl) {
        console.info(pl);
        $scope.Customers = pl.data.ArrayOfCustomers.Customers;
      },
      function(errorPl) {
        $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: i have received the data in controller but can not shown it to the html view

Comment: After `$scope.Customers = pl.data;`, would you `console.info(pl.data);` and show the data here?

Comment: I thought you were using `json`, but it's `xml`, then try [angular-xml](https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-xml)

Comment: my code in asmx    [WebMethod]
       public List<Customers> GetCustomers()
        {
            Customers c = new Customers();
            return c.GetCustomerList();
        }